# Calculate traveling time from several points to a same target, for different means of transport

Tags: r

Provided the following dataframe in which I have several source locations and destination (same destination for all, in this case):

```
lon_from <- c(2.885882, -2.885882, -2.885521, -2.887446, -2.885882),
lat_from <- c(43.291695, 43.291695, 43.296608, 43.298549, 43.291695),
lon_to <- rep(-2.885882, 5),
lat_to <- rep(43.297457, 5)

df2 <- data.frame(lon_from, lat_from, lon_to, lat_to) 

> df2
   lon_from lat_from    lon_to   lat_to
1  2.885882 43.29169 -2.885882 43.29746
2 -2.885882 43.29169 -2.885882 43.29746
3 -2.885521 43.29661 -2.885882 43.29746
4 -2.887446 43.29855 -2.885882 43.29746
5 -2.885882 43.29169 -2.885882 43.29746
>
```

I would like to calculate how long does it take from each source (`c(df$lon, df$lat)`) to their target destination (`c(df$lon_to, df$lat_to)`), according to different means of transport (let's say: car and walking).

I know openroutservice has an [R package](https://github.com/GIScience/openrouteservice-r) which has a function, `ors_matrix()`, which according to [official documentation](https://giscience.github.io/openrouteservice-r/articles/openrouteservice.html#matrix), generates:

> One to many, many to many or many to one: ors_matrix() allows you to
> obtain aggregated time and distance information between a set of
> locations (origins and destinations). Unlike ors_directions() it does
> not return detailed route information. But you may still specify the
> transportation mode and compute routes which adhere to certain
> restrictions, such as avoiding specific road types or object
> characteristics.

That seems to be exactly what I am looking for!

If I follow the description, I get pretty interesting results:

```
library(openrouteservice)
# openrouteservice::ors_api_key("<my_api_key>")

from <- list(c(-2.885882, 43.291695), c(-2.885882, 43.296608))
to <- c(-2.88276, 43.29196)

res <- ors_matrix(from)

> res$durations
       [,1]   [,2]
[1,]   0.00 142.12
[2,] 138.86   0.00
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to tame it for my case scenario. Currently I am facing two problems:

1. I need to feed it with a list, not a dataframe (although documentation specifies that I could use a dataframe, I haven't been able  to do it).
2. Distances are calculated from every observation to every other one. I haven't found the way to calculate the many to one option stated in the description.

So, here I am:close to what I am looking for, but stucked. Do you happen to know how to overcome these two problems or any other way to achieve what I am looking for?